# error in getting data from mysql in in android app

Tags: android, json

I'm trying to get data through MySql on my Android app using Json parsing, why data through Json is parsing?

**This is my code:**

```
            HttpClient hp=new DefaultHttpClient(new BasicHttpParams());
            HttpPost post=new HttpPost(Globals.webUrl+"diseases.php");  // add domain name as argument
                try{
                    HttpResponse res=hp.execute(post);
                    InputStream in=res.getEntity().getContent();
                    BufferedReader bf=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));

                    String temp="";
                    while((temp=bf.readLine())!=null)
                    {
                        s.append(temp+"\n");
                    }
                    System.out.println(s.toString());

                    Log.e("data", s.toString());
                    JSONObject obj=new JSONObject(s.toString());
                    JSONArray jr=obj.getJSONArray("ar");
                    for(int i=0;i<jr.length();i++)
                    {
                        JSONObject jb=jr.getJSONObject(i);
                        if(jb!=null)
                        //ar.add(jb.get("id").toString());
                        ar.add(jb.get("disease").toString());
                        //adp.add(jb.get("diseases").toString());
                        arDiseaseId.add(jb.get("id"));
                        }


                }
                catch(Exception e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
```

I am getting data in PHP file (in Json format)

```
{"ar":[{"id":"1","disease":"Achondroplsia"},{"id":"2","disease":"Acidic Reflux"},{"id":"3","disease":"Acne"},{"id":"4","disease":"Addison's Disease"},{"id":"5","disease":"Alcoholism"},{"id":"6","disease":"Allergies"},{"id":"7","disease":"Alzheimer's Disease"},{"id":"8","disease":"Amenorrhea"},{"id":"9","disease":"Anal Fissure"},{"id":"10","disease":"Anemia"},{"id":"11","disease":"Angina Pectoris"},{"id":"12","disease":"Anorexia Nervosa"},{"id":"13","disease":"Anthrax"},{"id":"14","disease":"Anxiety Disorder"},{"id":"15","disease":"Appendicitis"},{"id":"16","disease":"Arthritis"},{"id":"17","disease":"Asthma"},{"id":"18","disease":"Autism"},{"id":"19","disease":"Avian influenza"},{"id":"20","disease":"BPD"},{"id":"21","disease":"Back Pain"},{"id":"22","disease":"Baldness"}]}
```

But not in Android app.

Comment: what error are yuo getting in android app?

Comment: there is no error in adroid app but also m nt receiving any data!!!

Comment: check whether you are getting exception or not, and keep habit of debugging code.

Comment: Check what is the content of `Globals.webUrl` variable - maybe it is missing `/` at the end?

Comment: there is no exception and the data in stringBuilder 's' is null

Comment: You add this line in Manifest.xml: `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />`

Comment: Globals.weburl has url same and nothing missing

Comment: yes perrmision is added

Comment: e.printstack... check logcat.. you might be getting exception stack

Comment: in log cat m getting these line

04-06 14:42:42.060: D/libc-netbsd(4399): [getaddrinfo]: hostname=192.168.43.158; servname=(null); netid=0; mark=0
04-06 14:42:42.060: D/libc-netbsd(4399): [getaddrinfo]: ai_addrlen=0; ai_canonname=(null); ai_flags=4; ai_family=0
04-06 14:42:42.061: I/System.out(4399): [socket][3] connection /192.168.43.158:80;LocalPort=49269(0)
04-06 14:42:42.061: I/System.out(4399): [CDS]connect[/192.168.43.158:80]

Answer (score 1):

use volley library for json parsing, it is easy to understand and implement. [Android JSON parsing using Volley](http://www.androidhive.info/2014/09/android-json-parsing-using-volley/)

Comment: hi @lavisha if it is helpful to u please check it as answer accepted.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
DefaultHttpClient   hp = new DefaultHttpClient(new BasicHttpParams());
HttpPost post = new HttpPost(Globals.webUrl+"diseases.php");
// Depends on your web service
post.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");

InputStream in = null;
String result = null;
try {
    HttpResponse res = hp.execute(post);           
    HttpEntity entity = res.getEntity();

    in = entity.getContent();
    // json is UTF-8 by default
    BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in, "UTF-8"), 8);
    StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();

    String temp = null;
    while ((temp = bf.readLine()) != null)
    {
        s.append(temp + "\n");
    }
    Log.e("data", s.toString());
    result = s.toString();

    JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(result);
    JSONArray jr = jObject.getJSONArray("ar");
    for (int i=0; i < jr.length(); i++)
    {
        try {
            JSONObject jb = jr.getJSONObject(i);
            if(jb!=null)
            //ar.add(jb.get("id").toString());
            ar.add(jb.get("disease").toString());
            //adp.add(jb.get("diseases").toString());
            arDiseaseId.add(jb.get("id"));
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // Oops
        }
    }
} catch (Exception e) { 
    // Oops
}
finally {
    try{if(in != null)in.close();}catch(Exception squish){}
}
```

If it still doesn't work, I think your server has the problem. I've checked this code and it working.